# How do I create a "Share-Button" in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, share-button

I developed an App in which you can shoot a white ball on a rotating Square and if you hit the square in the white area you get one more point on your score.
Now I want to create a "Share-Button" to get more people finding out about my App.

So my question is:
How do I create a "Share-Button" to share your high score on social media?

My App is already available on the Apple Appstore and the Google Play Store.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cubedupe/id1315140839?l=de&ls=1&mt=8
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NeverBored.CubeDupe&hl=de

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Button to social Media Unity (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384547/share-button-to-social-media-unity-android)